# Where is Rhythmbox's playlist information stored?

Tags: rhythmbox, playlists

I want to know where playlists, created in/with Rhythmbox are stored and located? I need those files, in order to import all of my Rhythmbox playlists into Banshee.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The global playlists is stored in:

```
/usr/share/rhythmbox/playlists.xml
```

Whereas the local playlists is stored in:

```
~/.local/share/rhythmbox/playlists.xml
```